# Why fwidth behaves differently?

Tags: glsl, webgl

I'm working on a WebGL project to create isolines on a 3D surface on macOS/amd GPU. My idea is to colour the pixels based on elevation in fragment shader. With some optimizations, I can achieve a relatively consistent line width and I am happy about that. However when I tested it on windows it behaves differently.

Then I figured out it's because of *fwidth()*. I use *fwidth()* to prevent fragment shader from coloring the whole horizontal plane when it happens to locate at a isolevel. Please see the screenshot:
[image: without_fwidth]

I solved this issue by adding the follow glsl line:

```
    if (fwidth(vPositionZ) < 0.001) { /**then do not colour isoline on these pixels**/ };
```

It works very well on macOS since I got this:
[image: with_fwidth].
However, on windows/nvidia GPU all isolines are gone because *fwidth(vPositionZ)* always evaluates to 0.0. Which doesn't make sense to me.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any better way to solve the issue presented in the first screenshot? Thank you all!

EDIT:
Here I attach my fragment shader. It's simplified but I think that's all relevant. I know looping is slow but for now I'm not worried about it.

```
uniform float zmin; // min elevation
uniform vec3 lineColor;
varying float vPositionZ; // elevation value for each vertex
float interval;
vec3 originColor = finalColor.rgb; // original surface color

for ( int i = 0; i < COUNT; i ++ ) {
    float elevation  = zmin + float( i + 1 ) * interval;
    lineColor = mix( originColor, lineColor, step( 0.001, fwidth(vPositionZ)));

    if ( vPositionZ <= elevation + lineWidth && vPositionZ >= elevation - lineWidth ) {
        finalColor.rgb = lineColor;
    }
    // same thing but without condition:
    // finalColor.rgb = mix( mix( originColor, lineColor, step(elevation - lineWidth, vPositionZ) ),
    //                     originColor,
    //                     step(elevation + lineWidth, vPositionZ) );
}
gl_FragColor = finalColor;
```

Environment: WebGL2.0, es version 300, chrome browser.

Comment: can you show the entire shader? In any case try to remove all conditional logic. use `step` or `mix` or `* 0` or `* 1`. We can't tell you the issue if you don't show the code.

Comment: @gman thanks for suggestion. Shader code added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put fwidth(vPosistionZ) before the loop will work. Otherwise, fwidth() evaluates anything to 0 if it's inside a loop.
I suspect this is a bug with Nvidia GPU.